# I've just started Python and my code isn't working

Tags: python, list

I want to show you two examples.
This code right there is working:

```
fruits=["banana", "cherry", "apple"]
print(fruits[0][2])
```

And I get `'n'` answer so I wanted try this method to numbers but it didn't work:

```
grades=[87,34,65,23,90]
print(grades[1][0])
```

I expected to get `'3'` answer but I get error. I wonder why.

Comment: You can index a string but you can't index an integer: `"banana"[2]` is valid but `34[0]` is not

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grades=[87,34,65,23,90] 
print(str(grades[1])[0])
```

The problem is that 87 is an integer, try converting it to string.